# Does changing X, Y, Width or Height of a Rectangle also change left,right,top,bottom of a Rectangle automactially?

Tags: .net, drawing, system.drawing, delphi-prism

I am still trying to get my program to work with .Net Rectangle shape. My question is this. If you change X,Y,Width or Height of a Rectangle, will it automatically change other properties of a Rectangle such as Top/Bottom/Right/Left.

For instance, if I want the Right property of a rectangle changed can I do the following.

```
e: System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs;
dragRect.width := e.X - dragRect.X;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will.  The get-only properties on Rectangle are inferred from the settable properties.

Comment: @ Nicole I just wrote a simple program to confirm the answer and it does update the top/bottom/right/left properties. Thanks